# Accidentally ran mkfs.vfat on my backup drive

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ext4, mkfs, vfat

I ran mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb (whole device, not just one partition) on my backup drive, ironic, right. Is there any way to recover my files.

Comment: You don't have to as you still have the originals. And if your backup drive contained more than the originals you have on the drive you backed up from, I would not call that a backup drive and it would need a backup as well.

Answer (score 2):

First, are you sure you destroyed your data? `mkfs.vfat` wouldn't run on a whole disk unless you specified `-I` flag. `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` outputs no partition?

If so, you may have a luck with `testdisk`. It's a very useful tool to retrieve your deleted partitions. Just run `testdisk /dev/sdb` and choose "Analyze". Most of the time, it is able to find your deleted partition, and you may be lucky with your data.